# Nova BelongsToMany Field: Cannot update attached product, dropdown is disabled

Tags: laravel, relationship, laravel-nova

I have a `BelongsToMany` relationship between `Users` and `Products` defined in the Nova Model:

`BelongsToMany::make('Products'), //user has many products`

The underlying models `User` and `Athlete` both have the relationship also:

```
//User.php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}

//Product.php
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}
```

When I try to update an attached product, the dropdown field is just disabled and I cannot change it.

Is this the default behaviour for `BelongsToMany` relations? AM I expected to remove the product and add the new (correct) one?

---

### Update

Because nobody had any suggestion, I will assume that this is the default Laravel Nova Behaviour for BelongsToMany Relationships.

Comment: Can you providee me with a screen of your code?

Comment: I don't like screenshots of code, if you need anything just let me know I will post it.

Comment: I believe that is the default behaviour. You have to remove the product and then add the new one.

Answer (score -1):

Have you defined the relationship in your model? In your case I'd expect to have the following in your User model:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
}
```

Then in your User resource simply have the following:

```
BelongsToMany::make('Products'),
```

This should result in you having access to a select box of Products in your User resource, and no, them being greyed out is not default behaviour.

If that's what you currently have but you're still getting this behaviour then post your code, otherwise it's hard to help :).

Comment: Yes I have defined the relationship in my models both ways.

Answer (score -1):

To update in a `BelongsToMany` relationship, you need to remove the old one and then attach the new one.

```
$user = User::find($id); // get user
$user->products()->detach($oldProductId);// remove old 
$user->products()->attach($newProductId);// attach new
```

---

Or you can use `sync()`

```
$user->products()->sync([$newProductId]); // this will do both at once(remove and update)
```

Comment: I'm not on native Laravel but Laravel Nova.

Comment: what does that means?

Comment: It means that my question is not related to native Laravel relationships, but to Laravel Nova (https://nova.laravel.com/) which is a backend administration panel for Laravel.

Comment: @Adrenaxus as I know `$user->products()->sync([$newProductId]);` should work

Comment: Again: I do not need a solution to update BelongsToMany Relationships in native Laravel, I need a solution for Laravel *Nova*.